# How to record the android appication testing in java using appium?

Tags: android, record, appium

I am not able to locate "Record" button on the Inspector window.
Using appium version 1.3.4.1 and 
      Windows version 7

How to record the appication testing in java using appium?

[image: Android Inspector on windows7]

Answer (score 0):

Try with one of the android tool "uiautomatorviewer"

Answer (score 0):

Currently Appium on Windows does not support "Recorder" feature.

Here is link: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5201

Answer (score 0):

Now Appium Support Record UI Elements Option, Please find the below steps to perform the same:

Step 1: Launch the appium inspector by clicking the inspector button:
Step 2: Set the APK / IPA file path (application file path) as shown below:
Step 3 : Click on Start Session, now you will be navigated to Recorder window:

Click the application UI and perform required action “Selected Element” Tab ie, Tap, SendKeys for entering the text etc.

Selected UI Elements will get exported to Recorder tab after recording the UI Elements of all the elements we can export the Java file.